# How to stop ebpf

Tags: python, c, ebpf, bcc

I use bcc to trace a function and use bpf_trace_printk to print some info. But when I stop the bcc script, there is still infomation printed from /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe, how can I stop it？

Comment: I wouldn't expect the program to keep running after your stopped your script. Are you sure there is new information being printed (or was it some remnant info in the pipe, that you had not printed yet)? Could it be another tool/program printing there? What script did you use and how did you stop it? Did you check with e.g. `sudo bpftool prog` to see what eBPF programs are still loaded on your system?

Comment: Can you please share the code?